# ServiceStack Redis: given an arbitrary connection string, how do I test for connectivity to a Redis Cache server?

Tags: redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I would like to know given an arbitrary connection string, how do I test if the connection to a Redis Server is established. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run a command in a new client like PING, e.g:

```
try
{
    using (var redis = new RedisClient(connectionString))
    {
        var connected = redis.Ping();
    }
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    //connection failed
}
```